# Firebase database authentication sign-up

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

I'm connecting my app to database with authentication using email and password in signing in users, the whole code is alright and has no errors until to running the app where the sign registration fails, help
Heres my code for App gradle

```
"apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gmail.yobimwaura.talktome"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
configurations {
    // Initializes a placeholder for the freeDebugRuntimeOnly dependency
    // configuration.
    freeDebugRuntimeOnly {}
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'"
```

Sign in activity java file

```
"package com.gmail.yobimwaura.talktome;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;


public class signup extends AppCompatActivity {
FirebaseAuth firebaseAut;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signup);


        firebaseAut = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(signup.this, login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (validate()) {
                    //upload data to database
                    EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                    EditText editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);

                    String Email = editText3.getText().toString().trim();
                    String Password = editText4.getText().toString().trim();

                    firebaseAut.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email,Password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(signup.this, "Registration Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                startActivity(new Intent(signup.this, login.class));
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(signup.this, "Registration Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        });
    }
    private Boolean validate () {
        Boolean result =false;
        EditText editText3= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        EditText editText4= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        String Email=editText3.getText().toString();
        String Password=editText4.getText().toString();

        if(Email.isEmpty() || Password.isEmpty() ) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Fill details to continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            result=true;

        }
        return result;

    }
}"
```

If you need any other code ask for it, once I press the sign-in button 4 it displays 'registration failed' yet the empty textbox tag is working once clicked, my app has successfully connected to the database firebase

Comment: show the logs please

Comment: and once go and check in firebase console whether you have switched on the email authentication option

Comment: Turn on email authentication on firebase and password length should be greater than 4.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: Event log "4:11 PM Gradle sync started

4:12 PM Project setup started

4:13 PM Gradle sync finished in 1 m 28 s 951 ms

4:13 PM Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources]

4:16 PM Gradle build finished in 3 m 16 s 785 ms

4:18 PM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

4:34 PM Gradle build finished in 16 m 20 s 529 ms
"

Answer (score 0):

@AlexMamo Heres the log cat, still cant find the error @AliAhmed @HarKal,

```
.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL of 10042 is denied.
2018-11-24 16:52:54.922 1060-1071/? W/PackageManager: checkUidPermission(): android.permission.REAL_GET_TASKS of 10042 is denied.
2018-11-24 16:52:55.174 1259-1531/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): onDataActivity: direction=2
2018-11-24 16:52:55.180 1259-1531/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): Change in state from: connected=true,enabled=true,level=4,inetCondition=0,iconGroup=IconGroup(4G),activityIn=true,activityOut=true,rssi=0,lastModified=11-24 04:52:54,dataSim=true,networkName=Telkom,networkNameData=Telkom,dataConnected=true,isDefault=true,isEmergency=false,airplaneMode=false,carrierNetworkChangeMode=false,userSetup=true,activity=3,dataType=13,signalStrengthLvl=4,signalStrengSlaveLvl=4,signalType=13,signalTypeEx=13,signalSingleMode=true,isRoaming=false,isPoweroff=false,volteState=4,subId=1,slotId=0,
        to: connected=true,enabled=true,level=4,inetCondition=0,iconGroup=IconGroup(4G),activityIn=false,activityOut=true,rssi=0,lastModified=11-24 04:52:54,dataSim=true,networkName=Telkom,networkNameData=Telkom,dataConnected=true,isDefault=true,isEmergency=false,airplaneMode=false,carrierNetworkChangeMode=false,userSetup=true,activity=2,dataType=13,signalStrengthLvl=4,signalStrengSlaveLvl=4,signalType=13,signalTypeEx=13,signalSingleMode=true,isRoaming=false,isPoweroff=false,volteState=4,subId=1,slotId=0,
2018-11-24 16:52:55.182 1259-1259/? D/guohao: getSignalStrengthBigIcon
2018-11-24 16:52:55.182 1259-1259/? D/guohao: strength = 4
2018-11-24 16:52:55.182 1259-1259/? D/guohao: slotId = 0
2018-11-24 16:52:55.182 1259-1259/? D/guohao: QKCommRunMode.getDefault().isLEOS() = true
2018-11-24 16:52:55.182 1259-1259/? D/guohao: QKCommRunMode.getDefault().getCustomPrefrence(QKCommRunMode.CUSTOM_SHOW_SIGNAL_5_GRADE) = null
2018-11-24 16:52:55.182 1259-1259/? D/SignalClusterView: guohao not CUSTOM_SHOW_SIGNAL_5_GRADE
2018-11-24 16:52:55.182 1259-1259/? D/SignalClusterView: guohao QKCommRunMode.getDefault().isCUCCVision() = false
2018-11-24 16:52:55.187 1259-1259/? V/QKCommRunMode: isForeignVersion mVersion = 1
2018-11-24 16:52:55.188 1259-1259/? D/SignalClusterView: setVolteState cancel notify HD--------------
2018-11-24 16:52:55.188 1259-1259/? D/QikuMultiSignalView: SetDataNetworkVisible mSlotId = 0 mSubId = 1 visibile = true
2018-11-24 16:52:55.188 1259-1259/? D/QikuMultiSignalView: SetDataNetworkVisible mSlotId = 1 mSubId = 2 visibile = false
2018-11-24 16:52:55.188 1259-1259/? D/guohao: getSignalStrengthBigIcon
2018-11-24 16:52:55.188 1259-1259/? D/guohao: strength = 4
2018-11-24 16:52:55.188 1259-1259/? D/guohao: slotId = 0
2018-11-24 16:52:55.188 1259-1259/? D/guohao: QKCommRunMode.getDefault().isLEOS() = true
2018-11-24 16:52:55.188 1259-1259/? D/guohao: QKCommRunMode.getDefault().getCustomPrefrence(QKCommRunMode.CUSTOM_SHOW_SIGNAL_5_GRADE) = null
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, make sure to add the context:

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(**this**, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
\\OnSuccessful
}
```